# Ant-Ivy-Scala Template: any suggestions on improvements?

Tags: templates, scala, ant, ivy

I just created a template project for Scala using Ant and Apache Ivy. I want to get the communitie's input on any improvements to the Template so it can be improved.

The Environment effectively consists of 3 files:

- build.xml
- ivy.xml
- ivysettings.xml

running **ant init** will create all needed directories.
I was wondering if there are any Ant or  Apache Ivy gurus around that could give some input. [The Git Project is Located Here](http://github.com/luigimax/Ant-Ivy-Scala-Template)

[And the Project HomePage here](http://sites.google.com/site/lukesprojects/home/ant-ivy-scala-template)

Comment: Looks cool, but what was wrong with sbt (scala 2.7, http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), xsbt (scala 2.8, http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/0_6_Summary) or buildr (http://buildr.apache.org/, http://faler.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/using-buildr-to-build-scala-projects-or-why-buildr-is-bloody-brilliant/) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend a **[sbt-based](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/0_6_Summary)** solution.

Clone with **[Git](http://git-scm.com/)**  (also available on Windows with **[msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)**) the [following repository](http://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template):

```
git clone http://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template.git
```

and start immediately with a fully functional Scala project (complete with tests).

See [Get Started With Scala, Sbt And Eclipse](http://www.mgutz.com/2010/03/06/get_started_with_scala_sbt_and_eclipse.html) for more.